# Something similar to the bizarre Koide formula?

Tags: approximation, transcendental-numbers, constants

In 1981, Koide found the [empirical relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koide_formula),

$$\frac{m_e+m_\mu+m_\tau}{\big(\sqrt{m_e}+\sqrt{m_\mu}+\sqrt{m_\tau}\big)^2} = 0.666659\dots\approx \frac{2}{3}\tag1$$

where $m$ are the masses of the three leptons: *electron*, *muon*, and *tau*, approximately, $0.5, 105, 1776$. Later, about 2011, an identical relation was found,

$$\frac{m_c+m_b+m_t}{\big(\sqrt{m_c}+\sqrt{m_b}+\sqrt{m_t}\big)^2} = 0.666649\dots\approx \frac{2}{3}\tag2$$

where $m$ are the masses of the three heaviest quarks: *charm*, *bottom*, and *top*, approx $1290, 4370, 174100$. Some physicists dismiss these two as just numerology.

I was wondering how easy it was to find such relations so, using a small set of constants, found,

$$\frac{\pi+e+K}{\big(\sqrt{\pi}+\sqrt{e}+\sqrt{K}\big)^2} \approx 0.33376\dots\frac{1}{3}\tag3$$

where $K$ is the *Khinchin constant*.

> **Q:** Let's make things difficult. Using three distinct constants $c_i$ that are a) **well-known**, b) **transcendental** (proven or not), and, c) like the Koide formula, the $c_i$ are ***not*** powers or multiples of each other, nor close to each other,$$\frac{c_1+c_2+c_3}{\sqrt{c_1}+\sqrt{c_2}+\sqrt{c_3}}\approx R$$ can you find a combination of $c_i$ that is nearer to some rational $R$ than $(1)$ or $(2)$?

Comment: *Some physicists dismiss these two as just numerology* - There's no such thing as “just” numerology.

Comment: But why do you want to find such coincidences?

Comment: @SS_C4: If they are very easy to find, then that explains the two formulas. But given a constrained set of constants, if it's hard to do so, then there might be something to the two formulas after all.

Comment: Off-topic, but this might be useful for coincidences http://mrob.com/pub/ries/

Comment: It is worth pointing out that even if it is irrational or transcendental, it is arbitrarily close to some rational as Q is dense in R. I think what you mean is "nearer to some rational of small denominator." In other words, something really simple.

Comment: @AlfredYerger: Thanks, yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: +1 but a $\pi$ meson and electron $e$ and a $K$ kaon don't fit together...

Comment: @draks: I'm sure you know that's the usual $\pi$ and base of logarithms $e$.:)

Comment: Note that, as told in the wikipedia page, if you put s=95MeV then (95+1290+4370)/(-sqrt(95)+sqrt(1290)+sqrt(4370))^2 is 0.675, not bad either but not so impressive and also (95+1290+0)/(sqrt(95)+sqrt(1290)+sqrt(0))^2 is .664

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to square the denominator in the last one?

Comment: Hint. Use Geometry http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9402242

Answer (score 6):

Given your changes (i.e. wanting limit of $\frac23$) I'm giving a second answer. Again the problem boils down to what constants you use and the following results are from a exhaustive search of a limited number of constants and some fractions and powers of them.

Using the same function as in my first answer

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x+y+z}{\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}\right)^2}$$

the following combinations of constants give results close to $\frac23$.

Note: $A$ is the Glaisher–Kinkelin constant, $A=1.2824271291...$

$C_{10}$ is the Champernowne Number in base 10, $C_{10}=0.1234567891011121314151617...$

$G$ is the Catalan constant, $G=0.915965594177219...$

$$f\left(8,\frac{\pi^6}{64},(C_{10})^3\right)=0.66666688...$$

$$f\left(\frac{2\sqrt2}{27},7\sqrt7,\frac{\phi}{3}\right)=0.66666689...$$

$$f\left(\frac54,\left(\frac{A}{5}\right)^2,\frac{(C_{10})^2}{16}\right)=0.66666767...$$

$$f\left(7,\frac{G}{4},\frac{C_{10}}{4}\right)=0.66666801...$$

Answer (score 2):

To take a random example, if $G$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) and $\gamma$ the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), then
$$ \dfrac{3 G^2+2 G+\pi^2-4 \pi}{\ln(\pi^2 \gamma G)} \approx 0.9999999413$$

Comment: I meant exactly the same form as $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x+y+z}{\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}\right)^2}$$

Using $e$, Khinchin's constant and the golden angle in radians ($(3-\sqrt{5}\pi=2.39996...$) then the ratio is 0.33359021...

The reason for this is that $f(a,a,a)=\frac13$ so you just need to pick values which are close together.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have anticipated this as well. If we try to emulate the Koide formula, notice that it uses $x,y,z$ that are ***not*** close to each other. (Approx $0.5, 105, 1776$.)

Comment: A closer fit (and also excluding the ratio $\frac13$) is: $$f\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\phi,Champerowne's\text{ }Number\right)=0.39975055...$$
But this does use two numbers which aren't transcendental.

Comment: I put the transcendental constraint because it is easy to solve in radicals an unknown $z$ in terms of $x,y$.

Comment: I'm revising the post to exclude $x,y,z$ that are multiples or close to each other. :)